# How to configure for session cookie as http-only

Tags: session, session-cookies, httponly

to set http-only I used this in web.xml

```
<session-config>
        <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

but it is not setting http-only.
can any one suggest, what may be the problem. and how to set it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which container are you using and in which version?
pay attention since true can be used in web.xml only since servlet 3.0

Comment: support for servlet 3.0 (thus for the code snippet you provided is in tomcat 7), anyway from 6.0.19 you can set http-only attribute in context.xml file in your webapp, documented here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html

If your version is lower than 6.0.19 the only solution I know is to manually add the cookie in HTTP headers through a filter.